# Sum Range with condition in Excel

Tags: excel, date, sum, range

I have an Excel table like this

```
      date (A)       value (B)
 1    2012-09-01     1
 2    2012-09-02     2
 3    2012-10-01     5
```

I want to sum the `value`s if the month and year are of the same as the current date.

The expected result would be `3` in the example.

I tried

```
=SUM((MONTH(A1:A3)=MONTH(TODAY()))*B1:B3)
```

but the result is `0`.

Comment: What about excel's `SUMIF` function?

Comment: enter by typing ctrl+shift+enter will make formula be "array formula", which is inline of what you are trying to do, it seems.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=SUM(IF(MONTH(A1:A3)=MONTH(NOW()),1,0)*B1:B3)`

This does what you said, and you have to enter this formula as array formula by typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, not just <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Only way I can think to do it is add a Column C and then sum it.
[image]

I've never had much luck with conditional sums that use indeterminate variables 
(now() in this case)

Answer (score 1):

In order to sum data conditionally, you are going to have to create two more columns and use the SUMIFS function in Excel. The SUMIFS syntax is =SUMIFS(the range of values to sum, 1st range to check condition, the condition to 1st range, 2nd range to check condition, the condition to 2nd range, ...). In order to use this you are going to have to add a month column (C) and a year column (D). Fill C1 with =MONTH(A1) then just drag the formula downward. Next fill D1 with =YEAR(A1) and drag that formula down too. You will get the following:

```
     date (A)       value (B)    month (C)    year (D)
 1   2012-09-01     1            9            2012
 2   2012-09-02     2            9            2012
 3   2012-10-01     5            10           2012
```

Then fill the cell you want your total with the formula =SUMIFS(B1:B3, C1:C3, MONTH(TODAY()), D1:D3, YEAR(TODAY())) and it should give you row 1 and 2 with a sum of 3.